# select drop down opening upwards in ie 8

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with a simple select drop down. The drop down looks fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox but when i try it in explorer 8 the drop down sort of floats of and aligns with the top of the screen. You find the page here (for an FB-application I'm working on).

https://utvecklingtesttco.se/fb/jstest.html

Please help!